# exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: flutter, gradle, apk

I am done building my app, and I am trying to convert it to an APK file. I am trying to run flutter build APK and I keep on getting this error. I have gone everywhere and still do not know the cause of it. I have also kept all the relevant information where they need to be. This is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/osuyaalex/AndroidStudioProjects/multichoice/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/osuyaalex/.gradle/caches/7.6/scripts/181f8ztwffnirbvka8qh2s66o).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              3.7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

this is my app build gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.



        android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.osuyaalex.multichoice"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

i have already created my key.properties and kept in all the relevant info. a solution would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try by comment out lines 10,11,12 and remove the text from line 32

```
} A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
```